# How to prevent form hiding TornadoFX

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I need to disable closing of my app (It works in full screen) by pressing alt + f4. I read other threads and wrote the following code:

```
override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false)
        stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
            if (it.isAltDown && it.code == KeyCode.F4) {
                it.consume()
            }
        }
        stage.setOnHiding { _ -> EventHandler<WindowEvent> { it.consume() } }
        stage.setOnCloseRequest { _ -> EventHandler<WindowEvent> {
            it.consume()
        } }

        stage.fullScreenExitKeyCombination = KeyCombination.NO_MATCH
        stage.fullScreenExitHint = ""
        stage.isFullScreen = true
        super.start(stage)
    }
```

The problem is that my app doesn't close but stage is being hidden. How can I disable the form from being hidden by pressing alf+f4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried setting the `onCloseRequest` to the **window** not the stage. On OS X, after I hit `cmd` + `q` the window minimises, but does not close. I guess the best solution I was able to get was:

```
//Method in my view
override fun onDock() {
    super.onDock()
    currentWindow?.setOnCloseRequest {
        it.consume()
        currentStage?.isFullScreen = true //Set the window to fullscreen again
    }
}
```

As I said, this behaviour is on OS X, I guess it will be different across various OSs...